# What is the length of the escape rope in the cockpit? specifically A330-300 (If possible)

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a330

I understand you could measure from height of the cockpit window, but is there any official dimensions stated anywhere such as FCOM or FCTM documents?

Comment: Do they suppy gloves as well for rope burn?

Comment: @securitydude5 If you are escaping the cockpit of a burning aircraft I'd be grateful for the rope instead of the broken legs, burned hands would be the least of my concerns... I doubt that this info is in the FCOM or FCTM. This may be in a maintenance manual somewhere or specified with a part number (ex: 00001ABC 6M Escape Rope). I'm not even sure that this would appear on a MEL.

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree with you fully but for heavier guys, I doubt there'd be skin left on their hands by th time they get down they might even let go mid way and break their legs from the pain&as for the ladies, I do fear for them however thieir size.  Doesn't have to gloves with 5 fingers cause wearing those may take time, it could be a square or rectangular material designed for that purpose, so easily accessible that if you have time to let down the rope, you should have time to pick it up.

Comment: It could be the bag the rope is kept in or incorporated into the rope, always at the top end of the rope.  The FCC should consider making it compulsory.  Engineers could come up with a better design rope tha incorporates safety, even the risk of falling of and braking many bones because some people may not have the strength or master the skill of dis embarking off a rope worse still under threat of a fire.  Consider over 55 pilots flying a boeing 747 or an Airbus A380

Comment: To be on the safe side, it's always best to bring your own rope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the A320, this can be found in the CCOM (Cabin Crew Operation Manual)...

[image]

So the A320 is a 5.5 meter (17.04 foot) knotted rope stored above the side cockpit windows. There are 2 ropes in the cockpit (one on each side).

I can't find the CCOM for the A330 but it should be a similar size.

Answer (score 1):

(From A330 CCOM) The length of the rope is 6.7 M. The maximum load is 181 Kg (400lb).

Comment: The length makes sense, but do you know why the A320's rope can support 900kg (see Ron Beyer's answer), but the A330's only 181kg?